# Knockout binding on first load with prettycheckable

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to make prettycheckable and knockout work together, I've seen there's been tackled  recently but to be honest I could'nt make it work when the property on which the checkbox (or radio button) is set on first load.

So I was just trying to write a simple custom binding, but it's failing. Both if isChecked is set to true or to false on first load it misses the first change and then it "grabs" it but obviously one off the real value.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.prettyChecked = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, valueAccessor);
        $(element).prettyCheckable();

        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            $(element).next("a").addClass('checked');
        } else {
            $(element).next("a").removeClass('checked');
        }
    }
};

$(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').prettyCheckable();

    var vm = {
        isChecked: ko.observable(false)
    };

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HHEwX/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your fiddle, now it works :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.prettyChecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, valueAccessor);
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        $(element).prettyCheckable();
        if(value)
            $(element).next('a').click();                
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).next("input").val(value);
    }
};
```

There are also full [css solution](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles).

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HHEwX/2/)